# How to configure xpath for OIM Webservice adapter?

Tags: java, soa, oracle-fusion-middleware, oim

I am trying to build a simple OIM Webservice adapter.

```
OIM -> calls ICF WS -> calls Partner Link WS
```

From BPEL, I have the following mapping

```
/ns2:create/userAccount/__PASSWORD__ -> /ns3:createUser/password
```

PASSWORD comes encrypted, so I've added a policy to decrypt the password before calling the Partner Link WS, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22999_01/doc.111/e38352/extnd_func.htm#CIHHJCHA)

The problem comes from this specific instruction from the OIM documentation

> Configure the SOA composite in the composite.xml file. To do so, add
>   the following entries within the  tags of the webservice
>   that requires password decryption.

The example provided in the documentation looks like this

```
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="oimcp/WS_CONNECTOR_OUTBOUND"
orawsp:category="security" orawsp:status="enabled"/>
<property name="passcode" type="xs:string">abcd1234</property>
<property name="password.field.xpath.locations"
type="xs:string">/ns6:ListOfUser/ns6:User/ns6:Password</property>
<property name="target.payload.namespaces"
type="xs:string">ns6=urn:/acme/xml/password</property>
```

target.payload.namespaces examples are provided by error messages when you provide something wrong

```
<12/03/2015 19h24min21s UTC> <Error> <oracle.soa.bpel.engine.ws>        
<BEA-000000> <got FabricInvocationException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
target.payload.namespaces property validation failed.
Correct format is : ns1=http://a.com,ns2=http://b.com
```

Also, mr Grigoryev [in this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3633925) says

> (...)the policy should be attached to the target partner link, not the
>   connector composite(...)

which makes some sense. So I've tried several variations here, like

```
<property name="password.field.xpath.locations" type="xs:string">
/ns3:createUser/password
</property>
<property name="target.payload.namespaces" type="xs:string">
ns3=http://ws.xyz.com
</property>
```

but all I get in the process is a message like this

```
<12/03/2015 19h54min24s UTC> <Warning> <ORG.IDENTITYCONNECTORS.GENERICWS> 
<BEA-000000> 
<Node /soap:Envelope/soap:Body//ns3:createUser/password is null. 
Ignoring decryption of masked fields.>
```

And then, the request comes in the partner link with the password encrypted (which is useless).

**How should I properly configure this thing?** I could not find any decent example on the web. Even this example (from a question that is said "answered") is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved

```
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="oimcp/WS_CONNECTOR_OUTBOUND" orawsp:category="security" orawsp:status="enabled"/>

<property name="passcode" type="xs:string">passcode</property>

<property name="password.field.xpath.locations" type="xs:string">/password</property>

<property name="target.payload.namespaces" type="xs:string">ns3=http://ws.xyz.com</property>
```

see https://community.oracle.com/message/12947258